# Load WordPress RSS Feed's in a custom PHP file

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to load different RSS feeds in WordPress in a custom PHP file. I can get the RSS feed template to load using the following:

```
do_feed();
```

This loads the RSS feed fine but it contains no posts. It seems that the Posts loop isn't setup.

Does anyone know how to I would go about getting different RSS feeds in this way? I will need the standard homepage RSS feed as well as comments feeds and category/tag RSS feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do_feed()` needs `$wp_query` and a `feed` query var to be set. So I guess you could do a custom query and set the feed var:

```
if( empty( $doing_rss ) ) {
    $doing_rss = 1;
    require(ABSPATH . '/wp-blog-header.php');
}

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );

global $wp_query;

$wp_query = $query;

$wp_query->query_vars['feed'] == 'rss2';

do_feed();
```

Comment: Thanks Diggy; that worked perfectly! Any idea what the params would be for WP_Query to display the homepage feed?

Comment: That is impossible to say, most likely the site's most recent posts? You could visit the homepage and use `print_r` to inspect the `$wp_query` global: `global $wp_query; print_r($wp_query);`